# How to disable Ads while changing to landscape mode in android app?

Tags: android, youtube

I need to permanently disable the Ads while changing to landscape mode in android app.Below I listed the codes:

**PlayerActivity.java:**

```
package com.grace.view;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.ads.Ad;
import com.google.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest.ErrorCode;
import com.google.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;
import com.grace.view.ads.Ads;

public class PlayerActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener, AdListener{

    // create string variables
    String YOUTUBE_APIKEY;
    String ID;

    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "LayarTancep";

    // create object of view
    YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

        // connect view object and view id on xml
        youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);

        // create the interstitial
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this, getString(R.string.admob_id));

        // load interstitialAd
        Ads.loadInterstitialAd(interstitial);

        // set Ad Listener to use the callbacks below
        interstitial.setAdListener(this);

        // get YOUTUBE APIKEY
        YOUTUBE_APIKEY = getString(R.string.youtube_apikey);

        // get video id from previous page
        Intent i = getIntent();
        ID = i.getStringExtra("id");

    }

    @Override
     public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
       YouTubeInitializationResult result) {

        if(result == YouTubeInitializationResult.DEVELOPER_KEY_INVALID)
             Toast.makeText(this, "Initialization Fail- key invalid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else if(result == YouTubeInitializationResult.NETWORK_ERROR)
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.no_connection), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else if(result == YouTubeInitializationResult.SERVICE_INVALID)
             updateYoutubeDialog(
                     getString(R.string.update_youtube_app),
                     getString(R.string.update));
        else if(result == YouTubeInitializationResult.SERVICE_MISSING)
             updateYoutubeDialog(
                     getString(R.string.no_youtube_app),
                     getString(R.string.install));

    }

    void updateYoutubeDialog(String message, String button){

        //if Youtube app is not available show alert dialog
        Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setPositiveButton(button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.android.youtube"));
                startActivity(intent);

                //Finish the activity so they can't circumvent the check
                finish();
            }

        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

    }

     @Override
     public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
       boolean wasRestored) {
         if (!wasRestored) {
             player.loadVideo(ID);
         }
     }


    @Override
    public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDismissScreen");

        // display youtube player
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(YOUTUBE_APIKEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad arg0, ErrorCode arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String message = "onFailedToReceiveAd (" + arg1 + ")";
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, message);

        // display youtube player
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(YOUTUBE_APIKEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLeaveApplication(Ad arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onLeaveApplication");

    }

    @Override
    public void onPresentScreen(Ad arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onPresentScreen");

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("OK", "Received ad");
        if (ad == interstitial) {
          interstitial.show();
        }
    }

}
```

- if I click any one of the particular video,the ads would be
  occurred.After I cancel the ads,the video will be playing.
- I need to disable the ads permanently.Is there any way to solve
  it.Thank You.

Comment: Well Its not actually in our hand to disable the ads in videos. Its done on the youtube server side.

Comment: @GrIsHu is there any possibility to disable the ads programatically?

Comment: @GrIsHu is there any way to stop these?

Comment: No. Not at all. Its not in our hand.

Comment: @GrIsHu I referred these site `https://adblockplus.org/en/getting_started` but it blocks ads only one Ip address like while in my pc.But in another pc the ads wouldn't be blocked.

Comment: Its limited to the single system. Thats why its blocking ads only on your pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to change the orientation configuration you need to find the same activity created again for orientation changes, here you will realize Android Life Cycle.

So this one will help you

http://www.devahead.com/blog/2012/01/preserving-the-state-of-an-android-webview-on-screen-orientation-change/[link](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2012/01/preserving-the-state-of-an-android-webview-on-screen-orientation-change/)